# Javascript Image.onload callback to object function

Tags: javascript, callback, object

This is driving me nuts - I have been round and round in circles, and this no joy. I am loading multiple dynamic images, and have a simple Javascript object which I instantiate for each image, and which has a callback to render the image once it has loaded asynchronously.

I have verified that the callback code works just fine on a stand-alone basis (ie. I can call the callback 'manually' after the image has loaded, and the image is rendered correctly), and I have verified that the image itself is successfully loaded (by switching the object's callback for a simple one line logging function), but when I try to tie it all together, the callback apparently never gets invoked.

I'm relatively new to JS and I suspect that I am missing something fundamental about the way functions within objects are defined, but despite a lot of Googling, can't work out what.

Please can someone show me the error of my ways?

```
function ImageHolder(aX,aY,aW,aH, anImageURL) {
    this.posx=aX;
    this.posy=aY;
    this.posw=aW;
    this.posh=aH;
    this.url=anImageURL;

    this.myImage = new Image();
    this.myImage.onload=this.onload;
    this.myImage.src=anImageURL;
    this.onload=function() {

        try {
            var d=document.getElementById("d");
            var mycanvas=d.getContext('2d');
            mycanvas.drawImage(this.myImage, this.posx, this.posy, this.posw, this.posh);
            } catch(err) {
                console.log('Onload: could not draw image '+this.url);
                console.log(err);
            }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two problems: first, `this.onload` is not defined at the point at which you assign it to the image. You can fix this by missing out the stage of storing the `onload` handler function  as a property of `this`. The second problem is that when the `onload` handler function is called, `this` is not set to what you think it is (in fact, it's a reference to the `Image` object that has just loaded). You need to store a reference to the current `ImageHolder` object and use it instead of `this` within the event handler function.

New code:

```
var that = this;

this.myImage = new Image();
this.myImage.onload=function() {
    try {
        var d=document.getElementById("d");
        var mycanvas=d.getContext('2d');
        mycanvas.drawImage(that.myImage, that.posx, that.posy, that.posw, that.posh);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('Onload: could not draw image '+that.url);
        console.log(err);
    }
};
this.myImage.src = anImageURL;
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, THANK YOU. Now you point out the 'this' referencing, it all makes perfect sense.