# JavaScript object with a texture

Tags: javascript, image

Hi I'm working on a little JavaScript game an I wrote an Object constructor for creating the SpaceCraft object of the game. 
The code of the contructor is

```
function SpaceCraft () {

var obj = this;

this.texture = new Image();
this.texture.src = "img/spacecraft.png";
this.texture.onload = function () {
    obj.w = this.width;
    obj.h = this.height;
}

this.x = canvasW / 2 - this.w / 2;
this.y = canvasH / 2 - this.h;

//Methods

//Draw
this.draw = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(this.texture, this.x, this.y);
}
}
```

In the constructor there are two problems:

1. The this.w and this.h are equal to 0 although the image has not a size of 0x0
2. this.x and this.y are equal to NaN, but they should be a number

```
var canvas;
var ctx;
var canvasH;
var canvasW;


window.onload = function () {
canvas  = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx     = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvasH = 480;
canvasW = 960;

canvas.width  = canvasW;
canvas.height = canvasH;

drawCanvas();
}
```

And this is the draw canvas function

```
function drawCanvas () {

ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvasW, canvasH);
}
```

What's the problem of the constructor? 
Thank you.

Comment: Where are you getting `canvasW` and `canvasH` from?

Comment: The image *won't* "have" dimensions until it's loaded, which is an *asynchronous* operation.

Comment: The image needs to be loaded before its dimensions are known, simply defining its src isn't enough.  `this.x` and `this.y` are probably `NaN` because they are string values (e.g. `400px / 2 = NaN`) but it's hard to say without knowing anything about the `canvasW` and `canvasH` values.

Comment: sorry I didn't post where I get canvasH and canvasW anyway I post it now

Comment: I have changed the constructor and now the width and height properties are fine, but the properties x and y are still equal to NaN. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The image has not loaded yet. This is why you are getting width and height. Use an `onload` event handler to set these parameters.

I cannot say why `this.x` and `this.y` are `NaN`, but it's most likely that `canvasW` and `canvasH` are not properly defined. Consider using `ctx.canvas.width` and `ctx.canvas.height` instead.

Comment: How can I do that? Could you write me the code please?

Comment: Well I found this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123906/javascript-image-onload-callback-to-object-function

Comment: I think that it's the same problem as mine